# Bootstrap open 2 different modal dialogs same page

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have a page where I want to launch 2 different modal windows. One for creating new users and one for editing existing users.

I show existing users in a clickable table and link to my modal `#edit` like this:

```
<tr  data-id="<?php echo $value['id'];?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" class="open-edit">
```

This opens my Bootstrap modal dialog:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> 
I ommited the rest of the code.. I grab this modal on its id="edit".
```

This works like I want - when clicking on the table entry, the modal dialog gets opened with a form I created.

Now I created an exact copy of this modal dialog, only changed the `id="edit"` to `id="create"` and created this button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-me" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create" >Create user<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></button>
```

I would think that it would now simply open my second modal dialog named `#create`, but instead it blanks out the screen, like when a modal dialog shows - but without showing any modal window/dialog.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happending or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this code open 2 modal dialogs in the same page

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="width: 100%;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">modal1</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="width: 100%;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">modal2</button>

<div class="modal hide fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



<div class="modal hide fade" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Found I had a form-group tag place strangely, while trying to place my modals inside yours. After removing them, it works! :) Thanks!

Comment: This is good info... but I'm wondering if you can use a class instead of an id for one of the modals? I have several buttons that open one modal, and an <a> tag that will open the other. I'd use the class on the buttons, and the ID on the <a> tag. Would this work with your code above?

Comment: check the html inside the modal divs carefully.  i had one closing tag </di> instead of </div> in the first modal. and that worked when it was the only modal.. when i copy pasted it into a second modal, even after changing ids and everything, the **first** modal still worked, but the second one did not. finally i fixed the tag in both divs and now both modals are working.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put it on two different div and it will work , i fixed it